# jstree: how to get the id of undetermined state of node

Tags: jquery, plugins, checkbox, jstree

I use the jstree('get_selected',false) to get the selected node of my jstree with checkbox plugins, but the result doesn't include the node with undetermined state .
How can I get all of the selected node include undetermined ones.

the newest version of jstree does not include the method 'get_checked', why?

thanks.

Comment: The `undetermined` state is used internally by jstree and isn't meant for you to retrieve, set, filter on or alter.  You would have to modify the jsTree plugin (or extend it) in order to do so.   Additionally, I believe `get_checked` has been replaced by `get_selected()` as they technically now do the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jstree version 3 does have get_selected feature and it gives you all checked items

```
        var selectedElements = $('#treeidhere').jstree("get_selected", true);
        // Iterate over all the selected items
        $.each(selectedElements, function () {
            alert(this.id);
        });
```

for undetermined nodes,

```
        var checked_ids = [];
        $("#treeidhere").find(".jstree-undetermined").each(function (i, element) {
            alert($(element).closest('.jstree-node').attr("id"));
            checked_ids.push($(element).attr("id"));
        });
```